# Rails: Record not found error despite record existing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to update a record that does accepts nested attributes and for some reason I'm seeing the following error on update:

```
Couldn't find ServingV2 with ID=843 for RecipeServingV2 with ID=151
```

While the error seems straightforward enough, when I query the database, the record does exist so I'm not sure why I'm seeing it:

```
> ap RecipeServingV2.find(151)
RecipeServingV2 Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "recipe_serving_v2s".* FROM "recipe_serving_v2s" WHERE "recipe_serving_v2s"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 151], ["LIMIT", 1]]
#<RecipeServingV2:0x000000011d6fc228> {
               :id => 151,
       :serving_id => 843,
        :recipe_id => 1722,
    :ingredient_id => 92,
         :quantity => 2,
       :fractional => nil,
       :created_at => Thu, 29 Jun 2023 12:36:52.200198000 EDT -04:00,
       :updated_at => Thu, 29 Jun 2023 12:36:52.200198000 EDT -04:00
}

 > ServingV2.find(843)
  ServingV2 Load (4.2ms)  SELECT "serving_v2s".* FROM "serving_v2s" WHERE "serving_v2s"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 843], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 =>
 #<ServingV2:0x000000011d8ceec0
 id: 843,
 description: "'1 tbsp' converted to 1 tablespoon",
 measurement_description: "'serving' converted to 1 tablespoon",
 unit: "tbsp",
 amount: 1,
 ingredient_id: 92,
 coachcare_id: "22349718",
 created_at: Thu, 29 Jun 2023 12:36:52.195844000 EDT -04:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 29 Jun 2023 12:36:52.208951000 EDT -04:00>
```

EDIT:
This error arises in my controller when the following line is called:

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @recipe.update(recipe_params) # error occurs here.  Logs don't contain any additional information

        handle_program_approval

        format.html { redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipe was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @recipe }
      else
        p "failure", @recipe.errors
        p @recipe.errors.full_messages
        format.html { render :edit, notice: "Error saving"}
        format.json { render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here's the sql that throws the error:

```
  ServingV2 Load (2.6ms)  SELECT "serving_v2s".* FROM "serving_v2s" WHERE "serving_v2s"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 833], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:308:in `block in update'
  TRANSACTION (51.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:308:in `block in update'
```

Any idea why else this might be causing an error?

Comment: Can you share more info? maybe paste the chunk from the terminal leading up to the error.

Comment: Include the code causing the error please.

Comment: You have proven `RecipeServingV2` with id 151 exists in some environment (or spent a reasonable amount of effort to convince us it does); however you have not shown that `ServingV2` exists with id 843, nor have you shown where or how this error is occurring.

Comment: The query you're showing from your logs is for 833, not for 843. Show the logs leading up to and including the `Couldn't find ServingV2...` exception.

Answer (score 0):

could you double-check whether `ServingV2 with ID=843` you are looking for? Because the log you shared, it's looking for a `ServingV2 with ID=833`

```
  ServingV2 Load (2.6ms)  SELECT "serving_v2s".* FROM "serving_v2s" WHERE "serving_v2s"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 833], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Comment: Strange.  They do both exist but I'm not sure why that ID is showing in the logs but not the error

Answer (score -1):

You're not seeing it because your query is not just by those two fields.  It's joined to something else or there is an additional qualifier or default scope or something.

Check your app sql log.  And include the line of code causing the issue.